# Pending Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

The constructor of a pending intent needs an Intent object in it from the current context to the next activity. In my app, I have only a single activity containing multiple Views. No Second Activity.

The Views are Destroyed or made visible on demand. Obviously I cannot add a View to the constructor of an intent. So how shall I direct the pending intent? Multiple views have been accommodated into the main.xml using the `<include/>` command.

Comment: Can you give us more details ? What Activity you want to show ? What are you trying to do with your PendingIntent ?

Comment: y cant you give your activity only like Intent i = new Intent(this, youractivity.class); , PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,i, 0);

Comment: mvnpavan I cant do that because in the same activity I am maintaining connection with the server..if I do new Intent(this,activity.class) then the activity is re-created again,server connection also gets reconnected and not maintained..which i dont want..

Comment: Plumillon..say I have a list as a View..something gets added into that list dynamically from a server and a notification to notify that is generated..on the click of that notification but in the same activity without getting re-created I want to show the list and its updated contents..lets just say..its similar to our sms Messages list in our phones..

Comment: Have you tried passing the same activity in place of second activity in PendingIntent?

Comment: @AndroidMech do one thing give a popup to user on exit by caching backpress and register here and finish again i hope this solves some extent

Comment: Ashsh..yes I have..the activity gets craeted again..server connection which was previously established before gets disconnected..and within onCreate again gets reconnected..

Comment: Well, the server re-connection thing can be solved by using sharedPrefernces/Bundle. The question is, id this trick working for you?

Comment: I apologise mvnpavan but I didn't get your idea exactly..though i did get about caching the back press..but further..??

Comment: Ashish..I will try that..but can i really maintain connection in between activites using shared pref..I used a single activity because the server,SmartFox server I am using doesnt allow connection to remain established while switching between activities..do I took this decision..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to accomplish. mvnpavan already gave you good hint, you just need to do some additional work. First of all you should get familiar with this page http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.
It explains how to manage your application tasks and back stack. In your case you have 2 options:

1.Configure launchMode property of Activity in manifest. Setting singleTop should do the job since your are using just one activity.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackage.YourClass"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
 </activity>
```

2.Add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to your Intent(the one you are passing to PendingIntent):

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP**);

Please note that in both cases you can implement callback method of you activity onNewIntent(). Use it in case you wish to do some extra work when app is bring back to the foreground.

**Update:**

Regards keeping connection to the server I would use Service, not Activity. Then you can do whatever you like with your activity. This is the best practise. If you worry that Activity has no direct access to the Service API, you can bind to that Service. Have a look at this page http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html You can just copy/paste the code and your are done. It's very easy to maintain. In the future you may need to create another activity which require connection to the server. It will save you a lot of time and headaches :).

Comment: Really well explained..thanks a lot Loop for the support..you too mvnpavan..in the future I will take care in structuring my project..

Comment: I am glad I could help. If you are satisfied with my answer could you please mark it as the answer that solve you problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use pending intent to resume your application and not recreate it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, youractivity.class);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope it helps! ;)